# How to compare date and time in Angular

Tags: angular, datetime, ngb-datepicker

I'm trying  to compare current date and time with ngb date and time picker which is in JSON format:

```
var todayTime =  new Date();
```

Output:

```
Tue Jun 09 2020 17:43:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to compare this with the below date and time which is in JSON format and check if entered date and time are greater than the current date and time.

Output for ngb timepicker

```
hour: 13
minute: 38
second: 22
```

Output for ngb datepicker

```
day: 9
month: 6
year: 2020
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Create a date instance based on the output of your datepickers and compare them using Date.getTime() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
var objDate= {  day: 9,month: 6, year: 2020}
var objMinute={ hour: 13,minute: 38,second: 22}


function compareDays(dateObj,hour){
   var objDate=new Date(dateObj.year+'-'+dateObj.month+"-"+dateObj.day+
   " "+ hour.hour +":" + hour.minute + ":" + hour.second + ".000Z");
   
   console.log(objDate);
   console.log(date);
   return (date.getTime() / 1000) > (objDate.getTime() / 1000) ? true :false;
}

console.log(compareDays(objDate,objMinute))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date and time object to date with

```
 new Date("month day year hour:min:sec")
```

then check with current time stamp

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you got the methods of Date object.

By using `todayTime.getDate()`you will have a day between 0 and 31 so then with all the methods provided by the object you can get month, year, hours, minutes and seconds and just compare them to your json object.